# US H4 Visa docs rejected

Tags: visa

I and my husband applied for H4 Visa, my EAD & my husband's H1B visa renewal together, but due to the wrong date mentioned in the H4 fee check, all the H4 VISA & EAD docs are returned by the USCIS & application is rejected asking me to provide new fee check.
Now, what should I mention in my I539 in following questions?

1. **Is this application based on a separate petition or application to give your spouse, child, or parent an extension or change of status?**

Should the answer be -> Yes, filed with this I-539  or   Yes, filed previously and pending with USCIS.

2. Also, should I have to wait till we get an H1 receipt or we can send the whole packet which we got back and should not have to wait for new H1B extension receipt?
3. **Have you ever before applied for employment authorization from USCIS?**

Should I enter denied here as the application was sent back?

4. **Eligibility Category?**

Should I put my husband's new H1B receipt number(which he got from current extension application) or the old H1B approval receipt number(Which was what entered when we sent the H4EAD application with H1b)

I really appreciate your response.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't know most of the answers, but "have you ever before applied..." is a *yes* or *no* question.  You should answer *yes* and then, if asked, provide a brief description of your earlier application.